# Generate random numbers among multiple devices

Tags: ios, random

I am writing an app involving uploading images. I use `Amazon S3` to store those file. One concern is that I need to give each file a unique file name.

On each iOS device, I use the function **`arc4random_unique`** to generate random numbers.

My question is, will this method cause duplication across multiple device?

Because as far as I know, if I use rand() with time as seed, if two users try to upload images at the same time, the `rand()` function will produce exactly the same results.

Comment: Do the names need to be random? Or is that just how you're solving the uniqueness problem? Can you not have any non-unique names, or is there some probability you're shooting for (like 1 in 10,000 chance of non-uniqueness)?

Comment: @thegrinner, that's my method to solve the uniqueness problem. Do you have any advise for solving this without using randomness?

Comment: You can use a UUID in that case - it combines a device fingerprint and a timestamp, so it should work for your purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *GUID = [[NSString alloc]init];
CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
CFRelease(theUUID);
GUID = (__bridge NSString *)string;
CFRelease(string);
return [GUID lowercaseString];
```

Comment: The first line is pointless, as you are just creating a string that is going to be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have unique names for files, then using UUID is the way to go.

If you are using iOS6 and later there is a built-in method to generate a UUID:

```
NSString *uuidString = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
// Generates: 7E60066C-C7F3-438A-95B1-DDE8634E1072 for example
```

No need for dropping down to Foundation, or worrying about bridging and ARC.